# Issue with stylesheet overlap

Tags: jquery, css, overlap

I am trying to add a feature in an already existing application. In the existing code, they have applied styles for `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I am trying to place a horizontal bar in the same page for which the following code has been used.

```
<div id="tabs" style="height:750px; margin-top:10px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Center</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Receipt</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">

  </div>

<div id="tabs-4">


</div>
</div>
```

Now is there any way I can apply style sheet for the `ul` I have mentioned here in this code? I got the code for horizontal tab from one fiddle which uses one jquery-ui.css. In the application we use tiles.xml to apply style sheet and it has been designed in such a way that it is common to all pages.

Comment: *"Now is there any way I can apply style sheet for the ul I have mentioned here in this code?"* -- `div#tabs > ul`

Comment: `#tabs > ul {style: here;}`???

Comment: I tried that but I find user agent style being the only thing that is working. I used reset.css to remove still my style is not getting applied. Only reset.css rules the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with parent and child concept. use the your own made default style sheet and add parent class where id="tabs" and you can add any child class in you other div then you can apply properties which you want to use.

Comment: Please elaborate with example.

Answer (score 0):

add an id/class to the ul then in the stylesheet style it e.g.

HTML

```
<ul id="myId">
    <li>a list item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#myId {
    position: relative;
    // etc. etc.
}
```

TIP: NEVER DO INLINE STYLES.